# How to convert SqlDataReader result to generic list List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, ado.net

I'm trying to fetch records form Azure database using Ado.net I used **SqlDataReader** class for that. Even though the data fetch is successful, I don't know how to convert it into a generic list.

```
protected List<T> GetList<T>()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var query = ExecuteReader())
                {
                         // What Goes Here ?
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                if (_sqlCommand.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    _sqlCommand.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

ExecuteReader method,

```
protected SqlDataReader ExecuteReader()
        {
            if (_sqlCommand.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
            }

            return _sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        }
```

The Data Model,

```
public class Student
    {
        [EntityKey]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Major { get; set; }

    }
```

**NOTE**: I would like to know if there any other easy ways as well

Comment: `SqlDataReader` isn't a container, it's a cursor used to load data. You don't convert it to a List, you use it to load the rows, construct the objects and add them to a list. Or use an ORM or Dapper and have them do this for you

Comment: @MitchWheat that's not what was asked. If the application works with objects a DataTable won't help

Comment: The data reader results can't be converted to a strongly typed object without reflection. That's what microORMs like Dapper already do, along with optimizations that reduce the cost of reflection, eg caching types and PropertyInfo objects so they can be reused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlDataReader isn't a container, it's a cursor used to load data. It can't be converted to any container type. The application code must use it to load the results and then construct the objects and place them in a list. This is described in the ADO.NET docs, eg in [Retrieving data using a DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader):

```
    var list=new List<Student>();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var student=new Student();
            student.Id=reader.GetInt32(0);
            student.Name = reader.GetString(1));
            ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
    }
```

That's a lot of boilerplate, which is why ORMs like Entity Framework or micro-ORMs like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) are used to execute queries and map the results to objects.

Using Dapper, all this code can be replaced with :

```
var sql="Select * from Students where Major=@major";
var students=connection.Query<Student>(sql,new {major="Computer Science"});
```

Dapper will create a parameterized query with the `@major` parameter, execute it, construct `Student` objects from the results and return them as an `IEnumerable<Student>`. It even takes care of opening and disposing the connection.

Dapper works by using Reflection to identify a type's properties, use their names to load the correct fields and assign them to the objects it creates.

Comment: Thank You so much for the answer. But there is a one problem of implementing the code. There are so many models, so that I'm using **stored procedures** to perform queries. In a situation like that how can I get results ?

Comment: You can use stored procedures with Dapper

Answer (score 0):

```
while (query.Read())
{
  Console.WriteLine($"First column {query[0]}");
  Console.WriteLine($"Named column {query["put a columnname here"]}");
}
```

Read() will give you the first and next rows.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's only the start of an actual answer